# Combination with identical elements.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am given a word "Question three" and asked not accounting for order,how many ways  four letters can be selected from the thirteen letters.

My answer is since order does not matter  so it should be just  number of different combination of 10 letters with 4 taken at a time .i.e $C(10,4)=\frac{10!}{4!(10-4)!}$ As it has 10 distinct letters.Am I correct??

Comment: Not quite. You could also have repeated letters in your four letters - e.g. your word could be "hree".

Comment: so what should be correct?Is it $\frac{C(13,4)}{2!}$

Answer (score 1):

You have to break it up into cases, since you have 3 E's and 2 T's.

The easiest way is to focus on the E's of which there will either be

0, 1, 2, or 3 possibilities.

Further, there will either be 0, 1, or 2 T's.

So you have $4 \times 3$ distinct cases to enumerate.  Of these 12 cases, the only one that can be eliminated out of hand is 3 E's with 2 T's.

For each of the 11 live cases,

let $a_1 = $ the # of E's 
let $a_2 = $ the # of T's 
let $a_3 = 4 - (a_1 + a_2).$

Then the # of ways that a specific case can occur is

$$\binom{8}{a_3}.$$